# npm ERR! Cannot read property ‘match’ of undefined error handling

Tags: node.js, npm

When I'm trying to `npm install` my Nest.js repository, I get this error :

```bash
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/twalterspieler/.npm/_logs/2022-06-03T21_28_12_401Z-debug-0.log
```

Any idea on how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this error occurs when there is no `package-lock.json`.
To fix that you need to force clear your npm cache :

```bash
npm cache clear --force
```

Sometime it's enough. But if the error persists, remove `node_modules`:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
```

Then re-clear the npm cache :

```bash
npm cache clear --force
```

Then re-install :

```bash
npm install
```